# Access forbidden either read protected or not readable

Tags: laravel, xampp, vhosts

Currently I have multiple laravel project in my `htdocs` and configured like this

```
 <VirtualHost *:0903>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/svs_web_application/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:0904>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/api_tk/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:0905>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/svs_api/public"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
 listen 0903
 listen 0904
 listen 0905
```

I can access these projects and do some stuffs.

Not until when I configured another laravel project with this kind of setup

```
<VirtualHost *:0902>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pinoytravelreseller/public"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
 listen 0902
```

And I got this kind of error

> **Access forbidden!**
>
> *You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server*

Tried to include this setup

```
<VirtualHost *:0902>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pinoytravelreseller/public"
   ServerName localhost
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/pinoytravelreseller/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews   
  AllowOverride all 
  Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
  </Directory>  
   </VirtualHost>
 listen 0902
```

But still doesn't work is there any configuration do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

is there any files on that folder,

can you access by the way like localhost:902/demo.php,

demo.php just a php which say a 'hi',

if it cannot run and say 'hi' well,

I think you need to check is there any htaccess file on the root of project folder